# Is Active Perl Does Not Support any Extra CPAN Module?

Tags: perl

I am using [Crimson Editor](http://www.crimsoneditor.com/) as a text editor and I think it suports only Active Perl as a compiler. I downloaded some new CPAN modules for emailing etc etc. I added them in Perl library but program still doesn't recognize those modules. Can you please help me? Is Active Perl doesn't support any extra modules? If so, what do you suggest me for Perl compiler?

Comment: How did you install your modules? Did you use the _Perl Package Manager_ that comes with Active Perl?

Comment: Perl modules have their own method of installing. When you say "added the in Perl library" what did you actually do?

Comment: There are two projects to give you Perl on Windows. One is Active Perl, the other is Strawberry. Active Perl comes with its own CPAN mirror of modules that are curated and built (as in compiled and packaged) for Windows by the company that makes Active Perl. Strawberry is a community project that's mostly done by one guy. It uses CPAN directly. Both should play nicely with any IDE or editor that allows you to say what command to run your code with. Even if it just runs `perl`, then putting the  Perl you installed in your `PATH` in Windows will suffice...

Comment: ... But looking at the website of Chrimson Editor, I suggest you get a more up to date program. For example, take a look at [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit), which is the free version of the powerfull commercial Komodo IDE, which is sold by the same company that makes Active Perl. You will not have any problems there. But there are loads of text editors that bring syntax highlighting for Perl on Windows (in various degrees of usefulness). I used to work with PSPad for a long time, which is probably a lot like the one you have now, just still maintained.

Comment: ı tried to use Perl Packet Manager but when ı search related module in it, it doesnt show that module. Thats why ı downloaded it in a metacpan.org and put related module in library file in perl

Comment: You need to use `-` instead of `::` in PPM. It's confusing. But you can do partial name searches as well.

Comment: Is there a good reason you are using "'LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I'" instead of the letter **`I`**?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> *Is Active Perl doesnt support any extra modules?*

It does, but it has its own way of doing it called [PPM](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/ppm-perl-modules). Because many Perl modules require Unix tools and a C compiler, these are pre-built for you. Unfortunately these packages are often well behind CPAN release and are often missing CPAN modules altogether.

> *If so, what do you suggest me for Perl compiler?*

On Windows, I'd recommend using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/). It comes with a full environment necessary for building and installing Perl modules, including a C compiler. Then you can install things using the normal CPAN tools like `cpan` or `cpanm`.

> *I am using Chrimson Editor*

It doesn't look like that editor has been updated in over 10 years, and it's very Windows specific.  I'd suggest an editor like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). It's cross-platform, so you're not stuck with a Windows-specific editor, it has good Perl support, and it's kept up to date.

I would also not get too attached to relying on your IDE to do all your compiling and running of code for you. If you do, you're limited to what your IDE supports, and your IDE can get in the way of understanding your tools. Instead, I'd suggest getting used to using the tools directly. Learn how to use Perl on the command line rather than via the IDE.

Comment: Did you suggest Sublime because it's popular right now and it's the first thing that came to your mind, or do you actually use it? I remember you as a vim guy from your talks. I tried and hated Sublime, and every time I sit at a coworker's computer with it I fail horribly because all the default shortcuts are weird.

Comment: @simbabque No, I'm an emacs person (Aquamacs) but I wouldn't subject either emacs nor vim on new users, their interfaces are too bizarre and impenetrable and different from how anything else works. I recommend Sublime because it's cross-platform, powerful, highly customizable, and its shortcuts and behavior match the normal OS shortcuts. It's major drawback is its cost. It's certainly better than a 10 year old Windows-specific editor.

Comment: On Windows, Notepad++ isn't terrible. It's also free.

Comment: Oh. I apologize for the vim then. :-) I agree that I wouldn't suggest those two to new users.

Comment: Ok, ı get that, ı will change my text editor and compiler too. @Schwern ı am also very keen on to use Perl command line rather than using extra modules and IDE. But you know sometimes it is necessary. I dont know Linux, ı am working only in Windows platform. i did some research, ı think it is impossible to sent email a backup file by usng perl  without using any module..

Comment: @Schwern You can install ActiveState's MinGW bundle and build modules that way. https://code.activestate.com/ppm/MinGW/

Comment: Re SP "*comes with a full environment necessary for building and installing Perl modules, including a C compiler.*", And so does Active Perl. AP automatically installs `mingw` (the same compiler used by SP) if you don't already have a C compiler.

Comment: (You need need a recent version of Perl if you want to use ppm for free. But again, it's just an unnecessary extra provided by AP.)

Comment: @ikegami I think it would be best if you provided your own answer about using ActivePerl and CPAN modules.

Comment: @ikegami It would be useful to explain the current state of ASPerl, PPM, and CPAN for the OP and others including myself, rather than leave it as a series of comments. Last I worked with ASPerl, it was a while ago, it was very difficult to get the C toolchain and CPAN installs to work, and the PPM repository was indifferently maintained.

Comment: Since about 10 years ago, literally don't have to do anything. `mingw` is automatically installed if needed